# Question about setState inside function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I encounter a problem where I cannot do a setState function inside some function in React. I browse around the solution, and it seems I need to use arrow function or bind function, but i still don't understand how it works. Here is my piece of code :

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { teamsId: "" };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
      var x = "";

      /*
          some initialization here, but not really relevant to my question
      */

      //Test context
      microsoftTeams.getContext(function(context) 
      {
        //in this part, x is filled with the Id, but how to pass the value to state? 
        x = context.teamId;
        console.log(x);
      })

      //in this part, x is empty again
      console.log(x);
      this.setState({ teamsId: x }); 
  }
}
```

How to pass the context.teamId to my state?

Comment: The argument to `microsoftTeams.getContext()` is a function, a.k.a. a callback. So the `getContext` part does some asynchronous stuff, then invokes that callback when it's done. Async stuff is delayed until the current function is finished, so to get access to it you can put the `setState` call _inside_ the callback function

Comment: the problem is, it seems the setState function is not recognized. It shows 

"TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of null"

Comment: You need to convert that callback to an arrow function, i.e. `microsoftTeams.getContext((context) => { // setState here })`. That way the correct value of `this` gets passed into the callback